# How to find the common elements of among the columns of a data-frame when dimensions are not same

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['X'])

b=[4, 8, 9, 11]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['Y'])

df_f= pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
```

Final data frame is looks like

```
    X     Y
0   1   4.0
1   2   8.0
2   3   9.0
3   4  11.0
4   7   NaN
5   9   NaN
6  12   NaN
```

I need to find the common elements. For example, in the above case, the answer is 4 and 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to look for the values in X that are also in Y:

```
df_f.loc[df_f['X'].isin(df_f['Y']), 'X']

3    4
5    9
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

This will output a series of those values from X. You can use [`.to_list()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html) on the end to output these as a list:

```
df_f.loc[df_f['X'].isin(df_f['Y']), 'X'].to_list()

[4, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use intersection function to get the common values between two columns.

```
set(df_f['X']).intersection(df_f['Y']) #Output something like{4,9}
```